# What are the effects of forging a contract with a dragoon?

Tags: hitsugi-no-chaika

I don't know if it has ever been mentioned in the anime (or maybe I just don't remember), but what exactly happens if you forge a contract with a dragoon? I've tried searching it in google and  had no luck using the title as the parameters. The [wikia](http://hitsugimenochaika.wikia.com) doesn't say much about it, only that it requires an exchange of flesh to be formed.

Nearing the end of the second season, Toru finally forged the contract with Fredirika, and we can see regenerative abilities but not much else. What advantages and disadvantages are there in forging a contract with a dragoon? Considering how long Toru delayed it, there must be a reason why he chose to do it at the last minute. This may be explained in detail in the LN which I haven't read.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not really due to any advantage or disadvantage that Toru delayed it. It was because he wanted to follow the path of a saboteur (loyal to the employer), since he looked up to his brother Shin in the past, but he resorted to contract when he felt that he don't have enough skill/power to protect Chaika (the person he wants to protect, not just someone who hire him).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I feel as if being a dragoon, Cavalier is much more efficient whereas now he can't die unless the brain is killed and as we see he becomes much more powerful being able to take on Shin as if he was on a whole different level than him. He also gets Fredirika to constantly follow his commands which Fredirika was more powerful than his old self so he really just becomes so much more powerful, but he didn't do it in the first place for his pride and honor and stuff like that.